# Is caliphate a sunni concept,shia or both?

Tags: shia-sunni, khilafah

After reading Wiki on Prophet Mohammed's descendants i gleaned thus: through Fatimah (Shia fiqu?)they are known as sharifs hence caliphs and caliphate.Why are ISIS-Sunni claiming a caliphate? Do Sunni also ascribe to sharifs? A curious outsider.please feel free refer to wiki pages that can explain.Is it an oxymoron?

Comment: shiites are against caliphate